# Is is good practice to have same type of list in a class?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have created a class and I'm putting a list of same type as a property of that class.
Is it good or bad practice?

I am putting the same type of list because of I want to manage everything by only one object.
I don't want to create a single object and a list of object of the same type.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
class AssetSection
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SITEID { get; set; }
    public string PlantID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string UpDateTime { get; set; }

    public List<AssetSection> AssetSections { get; set; }

    public AssetSection(string des, string code)
    {
        Description = des;
        Code = code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does one asset "own" other assets, or is it the parent of other assets?

Comment: nope, The relation is not like that. It's pretty straight forward I just a list that i want to get through a property, that's it. @Jerry

Comment: Then, by the fact your asking this question, like your gut instinct says... this probably isn't the most intuitive structure for your data. You should just have a `List<AssetSection>` that contains your AssetSection's.

Comment: If you were to write asset.AssetSelections.First().AssetSelections.First().AssetSelections.First() what would your expected outcome be?

Comment: I got your point.Thanks @Jerry

Comment: `class Human` can have a  `List<Human> children`, right? so, no problem at all!

Comment: Thanks for your nice example !! @TaW

Answer (score 1):

That's ok. If you can imagine, you can design and use it.

Let's talk about entity framework. We create 2 entities like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when we try to get current user:

```
User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

`user` becomes an instance of `User` class now. This instance has a property name `Profile`, and this property has another property name `User` which has a type `User`.

It's called *mapping*. So, to answer your question: You can use it. But I'm not saying it's *good* or not based on the way to design the model.

Answer (score 1):

As a general observation, such a structure is known as a [rose tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_tree), or just a *tree*. It enables you to write code like this:

```
var t = new AssetSection("foo", "bar")
{
    AssetSections = new List<AssetSection>
    {
        new AssetSection("baz", "qux")
        {
            new AssetSection("corge", "garply"),
            new AssetSection("fred", "plugh")
            {
                AssetSections = new List<AssetSection>
                {
                    new AssetSection("xyzzy", "thud")
                }
            }
        },
        new AssetSection("quux", "quuz")
        {
            new AssetSection("grault", "waldo")
        }
    } 
};
```

If what you want to model is a tree-like structure like that, then it's fine. On the other hand, if such a hierarchy is *not* what you're trying to model, then it's likely to be confusing.

By the way, the code as proposed violates the [.NET framework design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections):

> - DO NOT provide settable collection properties.
> - DO NOT use `ArrayList` or `List<T>` in public APIs